# remove uploaded files after 24 hours in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

how can I remove uploaded files after 24 hours in my express app? I am not using database [ex. mongodb] since my server is very small (512 ram, single cpu). Or do I really need to have it to track uploaded file?

Also, I am thinking of creating folders for every uploaded files (per hour) so I will just check the folder name and delete it if it is over 24 hours?
ex. `09-13-2015>1am>` [all files uploaded within 1am to 1:59am]

Comment: If your web server is running on linux machine, a simple bash file will do

Answer (score 0):

With modules like https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron, you can execute code in a given interval, say 1 hour. With your idea of custom folders I would suggest you add a unix timestamp like 1442138734 to the name of the folder. Now check every hour (due to node-cron) if the timestamp is less than the unix timestamp now minus 24 hours and remove it if it is.